# Link to iOS Simulator file system from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I seem to remember a way to get to the iOS Simulator file system from within the Xcode 6.0 or iOS Simulator GUI, but I can not find this anywhere any more. Anyone know if such a link still exists in beta 5 or later?

BTW I know the simulated file system is now located in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*/data/Containers/Data/Application/*/` (previously `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*/Applications/*/`).  I'm looking for a link directly from Xcode, e.g. on some Schemes page.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the iOS 8 Simulator has changed from previous versions. Plus, every time you run the app from Xcode the location changes.

The easiest way to beta direct URL in Xcode is perhaps like this:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// where are you?
NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
#endif
```

When you open a Finder window to that location and keep it open, it updates automatically to the new location when you run your app again.

Further reading: http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer explains the location changes all the time so it's not possible to have a link. 
You can use the method above to print it to the console or save a small file upon start up that you can then search for.

Because I missed the convenience of the link I wrapped this into a small OS X app [Simulator Data Finder](http://ro-z.net/blog/simulator-data-finder/) and made it available. The website should be self explanatory how to use either for objective c or swift